# Embed python code in C++ with Sage

Tags: python, c++, embed, sage

I am trying to embed python code in C++. My script is (test.py)

```
from sage.all import *
def f(x):
    //do something
    return c
```

and This is my C++ code (main.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include </home/username/.../SageMath/local/include/python2.7/Python.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc; PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
int i;

if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
    return 1;
}

Py_Initialize();

pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);
/* Error checking of pName left out */

pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);

if (pModule != NULL) {
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
    /* pFunc is a new reference */

    if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
        for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
            pValue = PyInt_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
            if (!pValue) {
                Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                return 1;
            }
            /* pValue reference stolen here: */
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
        }
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        if (pValue != NULL) {
            printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
            Py_DECREF(pValue);
        }
        else {
            Py_DECREF(pFunc);
            Py_DECREF(pModule);
            PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
    }
    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
}
else {
    PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

However, since I want to import `sage.all` in my python script, I have to use Sage's python, not my machine's default python. Then I do

```
g++ main.cpp -o main /home/username/.../SageMath/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

and it compiles, but when I do

```
./main test f 3
```

I get

```
from sage.all import *
ImportError: No module named sage.all
```

And the reason is that it is still using my machine's python not Sage's python. I checked this by adding the line

```
import sys
print sys.executable
```

into my python script which gives

```
/usr/bin/python
```

I have also added

```
#!/home/username/.../SageMath/local/bin/python2.7
```

to my python script first line, to force the use of Sage's python, but obviously it doesn't work.

Would you be able to help please.

Comment: Have you tried running the program inside `sage -sh`?

Comment: Thanks, with some modifications, that worked!